# What does it mean that "Community <>" modified a question?

Tags: support, editing

I saw this question pop up to the top of "active" list, with "Community <>" user as the actor.

[What arguments can be given in favour of financial barriers for participation in elections or electoral debates?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/465/what-arguments-can-be-given-in-favour-of-financial-barriers-for-participation-in)

However, I don't see any edit/change by "Community" user on it, not even when looking at timeline: https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/465/timeline - the only timeline entries are from "Dec 18 '12"

**How can I find what the change was?**

Comment: That's "Community ♦", not "Community <>". (Alt+4 on an American keyboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It changed nothing.** It just "poked" the question because it had received little attention and no answers with score >0.

For a complete answer, see [this post on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/172266).